# Q-Test in mathematica

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematica, normal-distribution

I want to use the Q-test to determine outlier in my dataset. However, I cannot find a function to do this is in Mathematica. Does anyone know if there is a function which does this in Mathematica?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could describe the $Q$-test a little?

Comment: Not my idea of recreational mathematics, so I'm re-tagging as statistics. Maybe there's a better tag.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If $Q$ means the complementary Gaussian cumulative distribution function, probability distributions and normal distribution might also be appropriate tags.

Comment: @Dilip, go for it. OP can always change it if it's wrong.

Comment: Did you mean the Dixon Q-test?

Answer (score 1):

If it's [Dixon's Q-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Q_test) that you are referring to, it's not too hard to compute the statistic; it's the CDFs and quantiles that are a bit troublesome to do. As can be seen [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v16/i03/paper), the formulae for the CDF are rather complicated, which is why [Rorabacher](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ac00002a010) just chooses to use spline interpolation on pretabulated values (which I presume were a bit difficult to generate). I am however told that [the use of Dixon's test and other such procedures is passé](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1519), however.

Anyway, as I said the statistic itself is not too hard to compute:

```
qstat[data_?VectorQ, mode : Min | Max] := 
 With[{sd = Sort[data]}, (#2 - #1) & @@ 
    Take[sd, 4 Boole[mode === Min] - 2]]/(Max[data] - Min[data])
```

Choose `mode` as `Min` or `Max`, depending on whether you want to test the lowest value or the highest one as an outlier. Remember that once you've decided to remove one, it is poor form to reapply the test on the edited data.